# Changing the default mysql socket path

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu computer, namely mysql. I've various rails app that use mysql on the socket /tmp/mysql.sock, and as they're group projects I can't change their db config options.

"mysqladmin -u root -p  variables | grep socket" tells me my socket is  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock. I also have a mysql directory /etc/mysql.

I've read that I'm supposed to add the socket path to the my.cnf file in the etc/mysql directory, however it is locked for editing, and somehow reverts ownership immediately if I use chown to try and change it.

Please advise me how I can change where mysql sets its default socket path.

Comment: under which user you start mysql ie. root . so you must look under his home dir. you can also change the /etc/mysql/my.cnf to do that

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to get to the bottom of this, but have yet to find the definitive answer. It looks like the socket path of mysql is different between a mac and a ubuntu machine.

I initially created my app on my mac, where the socket path is:
`/tmp/mysql.sock`. When I tried to run rake db:create on my ubuntu machine it kept complaining that the socket does not exist. I had a look at what it is called on my ubuntu machine, which was `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. When I switch it out in database.yml it seems to work, but I guess I will have to keep both options in my file and uncomment based on which environment I am working in.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The solution that worked for me probably isn't recommended but seemed to work for me.. Just delete the socket path from your database.yml file entirely. I thought you had to explicitly state it, but if you don't it looks up where sql is installed on your machine and runs through that.